# How is 'via' pronounced and where did these variations come from?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, latin, historical-change, variants

Over the years, I've heard people say *'v-ē-ə'*, *'v-ī-ə'*, and sometimes the 'uh' is an 'ah' sound. (*edit*- It has come to my attention that 'via' was once a 'wee-ah' from Latin, but I don't feel like this helps my question. If anything, that just makes me wonder why there is that variation in the beginning 'ē' and 'ī'.)

Now, I'm guessing the difference between 'uh' and 'ah' may just be regional, but that doesn't explain the **first part** of such a teeny word.

This has been driving me nuts for awhile. **I've tried online dictionaries**, asking English teachers, and they all are the reason (as well as TV and movies) for why **I'm still clueless**. (As for the English teachers over my years of schooling, all of them agree to disagree with how it is said. I have one teacher saying 'no' to 'vee-uh' and one saying yes to that way and vice versa.) As for the dictionaries, they can mention the two variations but they don't explain ***why***.

*(edit)*

I guess the reason why I had been confused is because I didn't understand why there was a disagreement about how 'via' is pronounced. Can anyone shine some light on this as well? (I do appreciate the answers I received before I edited my question, but now they are insufficient.)

- Is it appropriate to pronounce it both ways or is only one way correct?
- Also, where did these variations come from? (Via is Latin, yes. However, in Latin, it only had one way of pronouncing it. In English, there are two variants that are questionably debatable, and that is what this question is asking about.)

Comment: Don't forget about the  "Vee" vs "Wee"- it is Latin after all.

Comment: When you're not under authority, say it any way you like. When you're with a  teacher, say it the way he tells you to. If you can get two of them in one conversation, say it any way, and say it the way the one left standing says it.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm guessing this is something that doesn't really have a definite pronunciation? Darn "/ But thanks :)

Comment: @Jim  Those teachers won't all say it the same way either. Robert Graves writes, in *Goodbye to All That*, that at his last school he mastered his "fifth different pronunciation of Latin".

Comment: @Jim And because it is an ablative, in Latin it should have a long *a*

Comment: *It* doesn't have a definite pronunciation. **I** have a definite pronunciation, which is /vi:ə/.

Comment: @StoneyB- Heh, I like it.

Comment: @Jim Also, many Vulgar Romans seem to have said /βi:aː/.

Comment: I use both pronunciations. Probably 'vee-uh' more often than 'v-eye-uh', but if I was talking with someone else who'd already said the word first, I'd almost certainly adopt the same pronunciation as them without even noticing it. FWIW, I suspect 'v-eye-uh' is a bit "American", along the lines of 'eye-rack' for Iraq (or is it 'eye-ran'? :)

Comment: I never say vee-a, only vy-a. Which accords nicely with the English dictionaries in JR's answer :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd say exactly the opposite, out of interest how would you pronounce viaduct?

Comment: @jk.: *Viaduct* would always be 'v-eye-uh-duct' for me if I used the word first. I'm not sure I ever hear people say that one differently (it's not exactly an everyday word), but I'd probably stick with my own pronunciation there even if someone said it "wrong" first. But for me at least, "via" is an 'ee-ther/eye-ther' choice - it makes no difference to me.

Comment: Awww, this is closed.  Well, *vaya* con Dios.

Answer (score 13):

This all comes back to the [traditional English pronunciation of Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin#Long_vowels), where a long or stressed “i” came to be pronounced with the `/aɪ/` diphthong, as in ***horizon*** and ***saliva***, or ***miasma*** and ***hiatus***.  You can see this phenomenon at work in the town of ***Salida***, Colorado, where the English-speaking locals now pronounce their town’s name `/səˈlaɪdə/`, instead of using the original Spanish-language pronunciation of `/saˈliða/`.

So depending on which part of speech it is, and the degree of assimilation, there are two distinct possibilities for the pronunciation of ***via*** in English:

1. `/ˈvaɪə/` (let’s call this the “English” pronunciation)
2. `/ˈviːə/` (let’s call this the “Italian” pronunciation)

However, that does not mean they are necessarily interchangeable, as there is some distinction here between the noun and the preposition. The preposition is more likely than the noun to have an English diphthong in it; that is, to use the first pronunciation, the “English” one.  The noun is much more often these days to be of the second, “Italian” pronunciation. This may be because most *“vias”* one encounters are from Latin, Italian, or Spanish, where the word is still used.

For example, in Louisville, Colorado, there is a road named “Via Appia Way” [[Google map](http://maps.google.com/maps?client=opera&rls=en&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&q=via+appia+way+louisville+colorado&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x876bf314cd68800b:0xa8ff1d080a98b6ec,Via+Appia+Way,+Louisville,+CO+80027&gl=us&sa=X&ei=9rGTUISpJsHkygHS5oDQAQ&ved=0CCMQ8gEwAA)]. (Yes, its first and last words mean the same thing.)  That road always gets the second pronunciation here, never the first. However, when speaking of a bus or taxi route that went ***“via*** Via Appia”, one might well use the first pronunciation on the first of those two words and the second on the second, making its route run `/ˈvaɪə ˈviːə ˈæpiːə/`.  No one here ever says `/ˈvaɪə ˈvaɪə ˈeɪpiːə/` making it sound like English across the board.

Similarly, “foreign” (unassimilated) terms like the [*Via Dolorosa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_Dolorosa) and the *Via Lactea* (that is, the original *Milky Way*), or places that have a road named *Gran Vía*, always have the “Italian” pronunciation, not the “English” one.  That is why you have Coloradans saying their *Via Appia* that way.

On the other hand,  a ***viaduct*** is always and without exception a  `/ˈvaɪədʌkt/` in English.   Other, less common words that work this “English” way include:

- Something that is ***viable*** is always `/ˈvaɪəb(ə)l/`, and the derived ***viability*** that accompanies it is always `/vaɪəˈbɪlɪtɪ/`.
- The trade-name ***Viagra*** is `/vaɪˈægrə/`, rhyming with *Niagara Falls’* `/naɪˈægrə/`, but more “viably”.
- A ***vial*** is always a `/ˈvaɪəl/`, **even(!)** when somewhat archaically spelled ***phial*** (which, after *Stephen*, is the only other word in English whose *ph* is invariably `/v/`).
- A ***viator***, meaning a wayfarer, has the somewhat unusual double-diphthonged pronunciation `/vaɪˈeɪtər/`.
- The Ecclesiastical term ***viatica*** `/vaɪˈætɪkə/` is the plural of singular ***viaticum*** `/vaɪˈætɪkəm/`. A *viaticum* is the Eucharist given during Last Rites, or more generally, moneys or provisions given for travelling.
- ***Viands***, a fancy name for provisions or victuals (“viddles”), are `/ˈvaɪəndz/`.
- The rare ***viameter***  is `/vaɪˈæmɪtər/` (for its meaning, think odometer or pedometer), which has a feminine rhyme with *diameter* `/daɪˈæmɪtər`/.
- The pronunciation of ***viaggiatory*** is unrecorded, and it is not a common   word. Perhaps `/vaɪˈædʒəˌtorɪ/`, or if you are feeling especially naughty, even `/ˈvædʒəˌtorɪ/`.

That’s because when stressed and assimilated, spellings like *via‑* and *vio‑* have a `/ˈvaɪə/` sound, like in *violin* or *violence*.  Only in unassimilated terms like ***violino piccolo***  do you normally get the “Italian” pronunciation. Normally, a word needs to have a *‑veo‑* spelling in English for the `/viːə/` pronunciation to prevail, as in ***alveolar*** or ***foveola***.

Comment: I say `ˈviːə` in general and so rhyme Via Appia, but `/ˈvi:ə ˈviːə ˈæpiːə/` would be too much. I'd say ['the DASH route'](http://www3.rtd-denver.com/schedules/getSchedule.action?runboardId=123&routeId=DASH&routeType=11&serviceType=3).

Comment: @Mitch: Actually, *Via* and *Appia* never rhyme, because they have differing stress and syllable counts: VI-a with two syllables and APP-i-a with three, and the VI stress not matching the APP stress.  Right? I suppose non-rhotics might  rhyme *via* with *keyer* and *pee-er*, and *Appia* with *happier* and *snappier*.  But I can’t. :)

Comment: My (very small) point was that I pronounce 'via' as `ˈviːə` (your #2), and 'Via Appia' to rhyme, not knowing what is standard.

Comment: @Mitch I also actually always use `ˈviːə` for *via*, but recognize that historically, it was often otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison with related words. I have always said /ˈvaɪə/ and had always assumed that /ˈviːə/ was an attempt to give 'continental' values to borrowed words. I say 'a priori' with English diphthongs /ˌeɪ praɪˈɔːraɪ/ but I also hear it with continental values /ˌɑː prɪˈɔːri/.

Answer (score 10):

Naturally, there is no such thing as one correct pronunciation variant.

The LPD-3 has some interesting data for (British) English:

vaɪə 88% (born before 1942 - 92%)

vi:ə 12%

Answer (score 9):

I have always heard it "vee-ah" (except in Latin, where it is "wee-ah").  However, searching for some pronunciations online, I was shocked to hear the majority of them say "vy-ah"/"v-eye-ah":

- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/via
- http://www.forvo.com/word/via/
- http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/via

Personally, I prefer "vee-ah", but Merriam-Webster lists both

```
\ˈvī-ə, ˈvē-ə\
```

so I guess either is correct.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a Br/Am English difference.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/via) only lists one pronunciation, unless you specify their [American English](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/via) dictionary, then it lists both.

My Apple’s on-board dictionary (New Oxford American Dictionary) lists both, as does [CDO’s](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/via) American English Dictionary.

Oxford’s online dictionaries show the same pattern: their [American](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/via) version shows two pronunciations, while their [British](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/via) edition only shows one.

As for what your teachers said, it’s beyond me how teachers can claim one is right and the other wrong, when reputable dictionaries explicitly list both pronunciations (at least here in the U.S.).

Comment: It might help if you mentioned which pronunciation was the one in British dictionaries.

Comment: @PeterShor: I figured the links would suffice, but Collins says ˈvaɪə and Oxford says ˈvʌɪə, which I believe corresponds to what the O.P. said was 'v-eye-uh'.

Answer (score 4):

In Los Angeles, CA, either vee-uh or vy-uh is totally acceptable. I say vee-uh but I've got friends my age who say it the other way.