# Syndrome: older pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, language-evolution, rhymes

Recently, I was reading *The Kenneth Williams Diaries*, and in one entry he records correcting some pronouncing *syndrome* (rhyming with aerodrome) to rhyming with *epitome*.

I cannot find this pronunciation recorded anywhere else. Is this just a quirk of his? Or is it an older pronunciation, fallen from favour?

Comment: I can't find specific information on the pronunciation, but the OED says there was the alternative spelling "syndrom" in the 1600s, which suggests the final "e" was never pronounced. Compare "hippodrome", "palindrome", etc. I'd guess Williams was being funny.

Comment: _Longman Pronunciation Dictionary_ gives /ˈsɪndrəʊmi/~/ˈsɪndrəmi/ as an older form.

Comment: Excellent first question! Welcome to ELU, Cheers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an old pronunciation of "syndrome" with three syllables (stress on the first). John Walker's [*Critical Pronouncing Dictionary* of 1791](https://archive.org/details/acriticalpronou00conggoog/page/n518/mode/2up) only gives a trisyllabic pronunciation, "si²n´dro¹-me¹" (where i² = the vowel of "pin", o¹ = the vowel of "no", and e¹ = the vowel of "me"). (This corresponds to the  transcription that [Christopher Ford](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/487948) mentioned in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/615718/syndrome-older-pronunciation#comment1565587_615718), /ˈsɪndrəʊmi/, given by the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*).

This pronunciation exists because *syndrome* can be viewed as a direct transliteration of Greek *συνδρομή,* with *-e* standing for a pronounced final vowel sound: compare *syncope* = *συγκοπή*, *epitome* = *ἐπιτομή* or *[Nike](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419371/)* = *Νίκη.*

The words *hippodrome* and *palindrome,* in contrast, are not direct transliterations of the corresponding Greek forms: they originate from Greek words ending in *-δρομος*  (*ἱππόδρομος, παλίνδρομος* 'hippodromos, palindromos').

I'm not sure exactly how and when the disyllabic pronunciation of *syndrome* arose. It seems likely that many people first encounter these words in writing, and so pronounce them as they are spelled according to the analogies of the English language. Aside from spelling pronunciation, it's possible the two-syllable pronunciation of *syndrome* was influenced by other languages such as French (where *syndrome* is always two syllables) or German (where the word has the form *Syndrom*).

Comment: Fascinating. In spanish the pronunciation has been correct all along, then, but curiously the ending "e" is not sharp as in it would be in english "e", and is closer to greek.